# Get the text after a specific word

Tags: javascript

Let say I have the following strings:

```
var Y = "TEST"

var X = "abc 123 TEST 456 def"
```

I would like to get the string from X that comes after the word that specified in Y.

In this example it will be:

```
var Z = " 456 def"
```

Comment: `X.split(Y).pop();`

Answer (score 44):

Probably the fastest way will be to use [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [`.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [`.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
var Z = X.slice(X.indexOf(Y) + Y.length);
```

However there are some other alternatives, like with [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var Z = X.replace(new RegExp('.*' + Y), '');
```

Or the one with arrays, proposed by [@AustinBrunkhorst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639365/get-the-text-after-a-specific-word/25639386#comment40060280_25639365) in the comments:

```
var Z = X.split(Y).pop();
```

Answer (score -3):

This will get you the word 'TEST and any words that occur after'

```
var word = 'abc 123 TEST 456 def';

var scrubbed = words.replace(/TEST(?= )([ A-Za-z0-9])+/, 'Howdy')
// abc 123 Howdy
```